# Storing a vector to database.. use a pointer?

Tags: c++

My title is probably very vague. I have a struture

```
struct {
 int a;
 int b;
}itemInt
```

and then I declare a vector

`std::vector<itemInt> ItemVec;`

And then I push a bunch of items of type itemInt to this vector. I need to store these values in a database using a generic pointer and then retrieve it later.

`long *lGenPtr`. I have to use this pointer.

I was thinking to declare and array of structure using the size of vector (since I dont have that info before hand) and store the values of each itemInt and then cast it to this long pointer. Doesnt sound very efficent. THis is used in a big program so needs to be as efficient as possible.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated. I am little short on time.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you're storing pointers in a database? On disk?

Comment: The pointer will be used to point to the data.. on disk

Comment: As long as the disk is always mapped to the same memory location, you're fine...

Comment: Pete Kirkham : Can you explain more please?

Comment: Are you sure really you need more than basic serialization ?

Comment: Rustic: What Peter means is that if you use pointers and the memory is loaded to another location your pointer can point to anything, reading from it results in undefined behaviour, something you really don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to examine the API of the database you are using. I am sure, that for serializing custom types you must provide a de-/serialization function, which tells the DBMS how to read/write your data... You cannot just natively cast a non-trivial type like std::vector to a pointer, you need to take a route via a specialized serializer the format and functionality of which must be specified by your DBMS.